# Showing Progress during For Loop

Tags: loops, powershell, progress

I have a ForEach Loop that I want to show progress on:

```
1..254 | ForEach-Object {Test-Connection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -count 
1 -TimeToLive 32 "$ipcut.$_"}
#^need to get a progress bar somewhere here^
```

I have tried using write-progress in various places in the above code, and can't seem to get it working as it loops from 1-254.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ipCut ='192.168.1'    ### not included in the original question

$arrTest = 1..254
$all = $arrTest.Count
$i = 0
$arrTest | ForEach-Object {
   Write-Progress -PercentComplete (
       $i*100/$all) -Activity "PINGs completed: $i/$all"  -Status 'Working'
   Test-Connection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -count 1 -TimeToLive 32 "$ipcut.$_"
   $i++
}
```

Reference: [Write-Progress cmdlet](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821879):

> The `Write-Progress` cmdlet displays a progress bar in a Windows
>   PowerShell command window that depicts the status of a running command
>   or script. You can select the indicators that the bar reflects and the
>   text that appears above and below the progress bar.

**Edit**: rewriting above code as a one-liner is easy: just separate particular commands by a semicolon (`;`) instead of line breaks:

```
$arr=1..254; $all=$arr.Count; $i=0; $arr|ForEach-Object{Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($i*100/$all) -Activity "PINGs completed: $i/$all"  -Status 'Working'; Test-Connection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -count 1 -TimeToLive 32 "$ipcut.$_"; $i++}
```

or simpler with hard-coded `1..254` and `254` instead of `$arr` and `$all`, respectively:

```
$i=0; 1..254|ForEach-Object{Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($i*100/254) -Activity "PINGs completed: $i/254"  -Status 'Working'; Test-Connection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -count 1 -TimeToLive 32 "$ipcut.$_"; $i++}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Josef Z.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43772804/45375) shows a viable solution.

Your specific desire to get a progress bar simply by inserting a `Write-Progress` command into your existing command's `ForEach-Object` script block is impossible, however:

**The script block passed to `ForEach-Object` has no way of knowing *in advance* how many objects will be passed through the pipeline**, which is a prerequisite for showing progress in terms of *percentages*.

**You *must* determine the iteration count *ahead* of time.**

If you want to ***generalize* this, use a *function***, such as the following (purposely kept simple):

```
function Invoke-WithProgress {
  param(
    [scriptblock] $Process,
    [string]      $Activity = 'Processing'
  )
  # Collect the pipeline input ($Input) up front in an array, 
  # using @(...) to force enumeration.
  $a = @($Input)
  # Count the number of input objects.
  $count = $a.Count; $i = 0
  # Process the input objects one by one, with progress display.
  $a | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Progress -PercentComplete ((++$i)*100/$count) -Activity "$Activity $i/$count..."
    . $Process
  }
}
```

Again, note that all pipeline input is collected *up front*.

In your case, you'd invoke it as follows:

```
1..254 | Invoke-WithProgress {
 Test-Connection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -count 1 -TimeToLive 32 "$ipcut.$_"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't truly add a progress bar and keep your code as a single statement, but you can do it on a single line by separating the needed commands via semi-colons:

```
1..254 | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 0} -Process {Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($i/254*100) -Activity "Tests completed: $i/254" -Status "Testing $ipcut.$_"; Test-Connection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -count 1 -TimeToLive 32 "$ipcut.$_"; $i++}
```

This uses a `-Begin` block in the ForEach-Object command to initialize the counter `$i` as 0. Per the comments, with this approach we have to hardcode the total of the collection as there's no way to determine it programmatically from within the ForEach-Object loop, because each iteration deals with a single item from the collection. This is mostly problematic because you are piping in a number range, where as if you were piping in a collection we could use that collection's `.count` property to determine the total.

However, its also worth noting that you don't *have* to display a progress bar at all to use `Write-Progress`. You can just use it to display a message to the user (with no moving progress bar) which does at least still demonstrate progress (just not how far through the total job you are). Doing this simplifies the code to:

```
1..254 | ForEach-Object {Write-Progress -Activity "Testing $ipcut.$_"; Test-Connection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -count 1 -TimeToLive 32 "$ipcut.$_"}
```